# Require Mootools AMD module

Tags: javascript, mootools, requirejs, amd

I just downloaded [arian/Mootool](https://github.com/arian/mootools-core/tree/1.5amd) and checked out the 1.5amd branch. I've set up a simple project and required the Element module. For some reason it is showing up in the dom but undefined in the source.

```
define(function(require) {

    domReady = require('require/domReady');
    Element = require('mootools/Element/Element');

    domReady(function() {
        console.log Element // undefined
    });

});
```

Any ideas how or why that could happen?

It might be helpful to know that I'm using RequireJS 2.1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first off, I think Arian's `mootools-amd` was an experiment that was kind of abandoned and should not actually be used. mootools 2 (aka Prime) is written in CommonJS and can be converted to AMD wraps with `wrapup`.

second, you need to require stuff before your outer function runs, else - there is no guarantee Element will be resolved by the time you reference it.

so:

```
define([
    'require/domReady', 
    'mootools/Element/Element
'], function(domReady, Element){
    Element; 
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I did not know the Arian's amd was abandoned. I guess I'll move on.